# How to check is smartbanner shown with javascript?

Tags: javascript, safari, smartbanner

Is it possible to check iOS safari smartbaner state on javascript?

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=123123">
```

something like

```
if(isSmartbannerShown) hideCustomBanner();

isSmartbannerShown(){
    //magic here
}
```

Comment: Same question. How to detect via javascript if iOS safari smart banner feature is available?